# Check if multiple arrays of the same variable name contain any items

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, arrays, razor

The example code below uses a mix of razor and Javascript. The RenderChart function takes in dates. The  dates var returns an array of dates. I'm wondering how I can check all the date arrays combined to see if any of them contain any items or in this case date strings.

```
foreach (MeasurementTypeGroup group in Model.MeasurementTypeGroups){
    var dates =  @(Html.Raw(dates)); // dates returns []

        RenderChart( dates);

        console.log(dates); //console would display something like " [] [] [] or [] [3/2/12] []
}
```

Initially I was using an if condition to check the length

```
if(dates.length === undefined || dates.length === 0) {
    //do something 
}
```

this partially works, but it does this on every iteration in the foreach loop rather than on a total of all the date arrays. I'm guessing I need to return another variable and then push the contents of one into the other but I'm having an issue figure out how to do this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Are you just wanting to get all the dates into a single array?

Comment: Yes, I guess that is a far simpler way to explain it haha.

Answer (score 1):

you can use concat to combine all the arrays into a single one.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

```
var allDates = []

foreach (MeasurementTypeGroup group in Model.MeasurementTypeGroups){
    var dates =  @(Html.Raw(dates)); // dates returns []
    allDates.concat(dates);
}

RenderChart(allDates);
```

Comment: Would this work the same if I did it outside the context of the loop if var dates is actually a global variable?

Comment: I don't know the context of how you are using the code or what you are trying to get out of it, so I am not sure if it would "work the same" for you.